# Webmatrix change Shortcut key to Comment

Tags: comments, shortcut, webmatrix

I am using Webmatrix to write php code.
But i cant find the shortcut button to comment out code lines.
I want to change the shortcut key to comment out codes...
How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> comments code out. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> uncomments it.

There is a file called hotkeys.txt located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft WebMatrix\config` that enables you to change some shortcuts. The one detailed above is not one of those that can be changed, however.